# XDomainRequest in IE is giving Access is Denied error

Tags: xdomainrequest

This is the code I am using is as follows down below:

I am using IE9 and am unable to see the request being sent in the Network tab. I do have Access-Control headers set in the JSP as:

```
<% response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");%>
```

Code to get the AJAX HTML Content from the JSP:

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {

    var xdr = new window.XDomainRequest();
    xdr.open("GET", "http://dev01.org:11110/crs/qw/qw.jsp?&_=" + Math.random());
    xdr.contentType = "text/plain";
    xdr.timeout = 5000;
    xdr.onerror = function () {
        console.log('we have an error!');
    }
    xdr.onprogress = function () {
        console.log('this sucks!');
    };
    xdr.ontimeout = function () {
        console.log('it timed out!');
    };
    xdr.onopen = function () {
        console.log('we open the xdomainrequest');
    };
    xdr.onload = function() {
        alert(xdr.responseText);
    };
    xdr.send(null);
} else { ...... }
```

I am getting a Access is Denied Error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page**

In your example you are doing request to:

```
http://dev01 ...
```

And you should do this from HTTP protocol.

For example:
If your site, where js script is located: `http://dev.org`
You can do this:

```
xhr = new XDomainRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://dev01.org?p=1");
```

but this throws "Access denied":

```
xhr = new XDomainRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://dev01.org?p=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with XDomainRequest is that it doesn't respect `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.  Instead, you must specify the domain.  This can be obtained from the HTTP_REFERER header if you need to dynamically generate it, or if you are only expecting requests from one domain you can set it manually.  [This article might help.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx)

```
<% response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://dev01.org");%>
```